# .NET ETW is not creating event log

Tags: .net-4.5, etw

I'm developing a sample to create event log using ETW (Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.*) on .NET 4.5

Code compiled good, and I can get the manifest file generated, and manually install it through wevtutil

But when testing invoke the log, there's no event logs created in event viewer. Even my custom ETW tree isn't showing.

I merely named my customer EventSource like "ABC", does it matter?
If I try to reinstall the manifest file, it prompt me that's already installed.

How to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

nvm, I just need to open a **new** event viewer window, and it's showing good there.